# Attached Properties and updating them in the designer

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have created an attached property `Watermark.Content` which works fine at runtime but changing property at design-time does not cause the designer to redraw itself, even with the `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender`.

I have also tried all other options in `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.*` to no avail.  The watermark is hosted in the `AdornerLayer` which may be the cause of the problem.

Any help with this?

**Edit:**

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" Margin="0,0,0,5">
    <ext:Watermark.Content>
        <TextBlock Text="Email" Margin="3,0" />
    </ext:Watermark.Content>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Would you mind showing us your code implementation?

Comment: I found the reason its not updating (it also doesn't update at runtime) and its because I need to call `adorneLayer.Update()` which is easy to do, except, I'm not getting a `TargetUpdated` event raised when I change the value of `TextBlock.Text` in the above code.